# labeling the connected component in an image in opencv

Tags: opencv

I have written a piece of code that finds the connected components and labels the connected components with letter 'R' using cvPutText. Now instead of Letter'R' i need to print the numbers like 1,2,3,....etc according the no.of connected components. After that i need to find area and print the area of connected components as a text. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is my code:

```
imagelab=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(mor),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
CvMemStorage* contour_storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
CvSeq* contours;
CvFont font;
cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0, 2);
cvFindContours(mor, contour_storage, &contours, sizeof (CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
cvZero(imagelab);

for( ; contours != NULL; contours = contours->h_next )
 {
    CvScalar color =  CV_RGB( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 );
    cvDrawContours( imagelab, contours, color, CV_RGB(255,255,255), -1, CV_FILLED, 8 ,cvPoint(0,0));
    CvRect iconBox = cvBoundingRect(contours, 0);
    CvPoint center = cvPoint(iconBox.x + (iconBox.width / 2), iconBox.y + (iconBox.height / 2));
    int area = abs(cvContourArea(contours, CV_WHOLE_SEQ));
    cvPutText(imagelab,"R", center, &font, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
  }
```

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many way's to do that what you need is to convert an integer to a string. Just use a counter. My favorit is using stringstreams

```
for(int ncount = 0 ; contours != NULL; contours = contours->h_next, ncount++ )
...
std::stringstream str;
str << ncount;
cvPutText(imagelab,str.str(), center, &font, CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
```

Comment: D:\qtproject\finalvversion1\finalv1.cpp:122: error: C2664: 'cvPutText' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'const char *'
with
[
    _Elem=char,
    _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
    _Ax=std::allocator<char>
]
No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: I corrected the error and now i have to print the area of each connected component seperately as a text. can you give me some suggestion with that?